# is there a way to use the result of the LAG() function to LAG() that same column

Tags: sql, window-functions

I'm trying to create frequency buckets in sql, I'm able to calculate the number of bins and the bin width. I have a table like this:

| Zip | Bin_Width | Bin_Count | Min_Px | Max_Px |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07302 | 289285.717 | 7 | 325000.00 | 2350000.00 |

I want to create a column or seperate table that creates the bin widths until the count is 7 (since their are only 7 bins) which would look like this, the math is taking the first rows min_px + bin width and then take that value + bin_width.

| Zip | Lower_Bound | Upper Bound | Math |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07302 | 325000 | 614285.7143 | Lower_bound + bin_with (289285.717) = Upper Bound |
| 07302 | 614285.7143 | 903571.4286 | Lower_bound + bin_with (289285.717) = Upper Bound |
| 07302 | 903571.4286 | 1192857.143 | Lower_bound + bin_with (289285.717) = Upper Bound |
| 07302 | 1192857.143 | 1482142.857 |  |
| 07302 | 1482142.857 | 1771428.571 |  |
| 07302 | 1771428.571 | 2060714.286 |  |
| 07302 | 2060714.286 | 2350000 |  |

It unclear to me where to start, I know I need to use the LAG() function but unclear how to use the LAG to LAG that value

Comment: You don't. SQL isn't a linear program, it's set based; you either calculate each row's data independently (you can lag the inputs, but not the outputs) or start writing recursive SQL (which can be useful for traversing trees, etc, but is less well suited for "loops"). So, instead of reading the previous result, just write an expression that takes the bin number and returns the lower or upper bound. `lower = base + bin * width` and `upper = base + (bin+1) * width`. Then you can generate the 7 bins with generateseries, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check generate_series option in postgresql . since you didn't tag or mention any database system. Here is the ddl and sql statment.

```
create table stack_questions_100
(zip varchar(20),
Bin_Width   decimal(10,3),
Bin_Count int,
min_px decimal(10,3),
max_px decimal(10,3)
);


insert into stack_questions_100
values
('07302',289285.717,7,325000.00,2350000.00);

select * from stack_questions_100;



 select 
    zip , s.min_px+((id -1 ) * bin_width) as lower_bound,s.min_px+(id * bin_width ) as upper_bound
    
    from stack_questions_100 s,
    generate_series(1,s.Bin_Count) as temp(id)
```

### output

```
 zip  |lower_bound|upper_bound|
-----+-----------+-----------+
07302| 325000.000| 614285.717|
07302| 614285.717| 903571.434|
07302| 903571.434|1192857.151|
07302|1192857.151|1482142.868|
07302|1482142.868|1771428.585|
07302|1771428.585|2060714.302|
07302|2060714.302|2350000.019|
```

Comment: Lower bound should be `min_px + (id-1) * width`